# Azure New-AzureStorageBlobSasToken incorrect fulluri string being returned

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-powershell

I am attempting to use the AzureRM PowerShell Module to generate a new SAS Token for a Blob Container (and subfolder data) at the command line.
This process works when navigating in the Portal and manually creating the SAS Token for the specified file, but is failing when using PS

```
$SAResourceGroupName="someresourcegroupname"
$StorageAccountName="randomstorageaccountnamehere"

$StorageAccountKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $SAResourceGroupName -AccountName $StorageAccountName).Value[1]
$Context=New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

$tmpStart = Get-Date
$tmpEnd = $tmpStart.AddHours(0.5)

$Starttime = ($tmpStart).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
$EndTime = ($tmpEnd).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")


$SASToken = New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken -Blob $StorageAccountName -Container "ContainerNameHere/ToolsSubFolder/randomfile.ZIP" -Context $Context -Permission r -StartTime $StartTime -ExpiryTime $EndTime -FullURI
```

The resulting SAS Token that is being generated has the $StorageAccountName twice, and the formatting is being done in HTML, so the token itself doesnt have the correct characters.

(data scrubbed)

> PS C:\Users\lsierra> New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken -Container
>   "ContainerNameHere/ToolsSubFolder/randomfile.ZIP" -Blob
>   $StorageAccountName -Permission r -Context $Context -FullUri
>   https://randomstorageaccountnamehere.blob.core.windows.net/ContainerNameHere/ToolsSubFolder/randomfile.ZIP/randomstorageaccountnamehere?sv=2017-07-29&sr=b&sig=kXzYwqW%2BjKH1BAXwsBovVzCbGY2XzLxUY
>   BxKQNkeqns%3D&se=2018-11-02T18%3A02%3A02Z&sp=r

If I navigate to the Portal and manually generate a new SAS Token, the FullURI is correct, both in content and formatting.

PowerShell v5.1 
Windows 10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was caused by your last command:

```
$SASToken = New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken -Blob $StorageAccountName -Container "ContainerNameHere/ToolsSubFolder/randomfile.ZIP" -Context $Context -Permission r -StartTime $StartTime -ExpiryTime $EndTime -FullURI
```

In your case, it should be:

```
$SASToken = New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken -Blob "ToolsSubFolder/randomfile.ZIP" -Container "ContainerNameHere" -Context $Context -Permission r -StartTime $StartTime -ExpiryTime $EndTime -FullURI
```

So your complete powershell script will like below, just try it, it works fine on my side.

```
$SAResourceGroupName="someresourcegroupname"
$StorageAccountName="randomstorageaccountnamehere"

$StorageAccountKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $SAResourceGroupName -AccountName $StorageAccountName).Value[1]
$Context=New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

$tmpStart = Get-Date
$tmpEnd = $tmpStart.AddHours(0.5)

$Starttime = ($tmpStart).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
$EndTime = ($tmpEnd).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")

$SASToken = New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken -Blob "ToolsSubFolder/randomfile.ZIP" -Container "ContainerNameHere" -Context $Context -Permission r -StartTime $StartTime -ExpiryTime $EndTime -FullURI
```

My test sample:

[image]

For more details about the usage of the `New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken`, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestorageblobsastoken?view=azurermps-6.11.0).